# How to talk about the location of a place, which I visited in the past?

Tags: past-tense

I tried to find it out by myself, but I didn't succeed. Probably, because I didn't really know for what I should search.

I want to talk about the location of a place, which I visited in the past, but the place still exists.

It works the best with an example, I guess. Which one is better:

1. Our hostel was located in a messy area with many abandoned houses.
2. Our hostel is located in a messy area with many abandoned houses.
3. ?

My context is the following:

- I'm writing a letter to a friend.
- I'm telling this friend about our visit in a hostel, which still exists.

Comment: Frist one means that the place is no longer there. Probably demolished.

Comment: @Ustanak Not so: it does not address whether the hostel still exists.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context.  If you are writing a description of your trip, and this is merely one word in the description, *1. Our hostel was located in a messy area with many abandoned houses.* is perfectly correct, and readily understandable.

If you want to write one sentence, that is totally specific you could write

- The hostel *we stayed* at was located in a messy area with many
  abandoned houses.
- Or *We stayed at* a hostel which was located in a messy    area with many
  abandoned houses.

Comment: Neither states that the hostel "still exists" as asked in the question.

Comment: The question, as stated in the title is what I answered.  As I understood the question, he just wanted to talk about a building that he visited in the past.  Whether it still exists or not does not change the construction of the sentence.  The context around the sentence is important.  I believe, that perhaps, he thought there might be a different construction of the sentence depending on whether the building was still there or not, as is sometime the case in other languages.

Comment: @Msfolly: Yes, that's why I'm asking. I don't want to say, that the hostel doesn't exists anymore, but it sounds like I say that, when I write "Our hostel was..".

Comment: Okay, then.  I stand by my answer.  Whether or not a bulldozer wipes the hostel you stayed at off the map today has nothing to do with how you would construct a sentence about where it was to a friend in a letter.  The "still exists" part of the subsequent explanation was sort of a red herring to the intended question as stated in your title.  How nice that you are taking time to write a friend in your non-native language...